# messages.properties keys with multiple dots not working

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I am using a messages.properties bundle for my .xhtml page. I can access the keys and use them if they have a single name. Chaining keys for the same category and dividing them by `.` causes problems.

e.g.
messages.properties:

```
bookTitle=Title
```

I load my bundle like this:

```
<f:loadBundle var="msg" basename="messages"/>
```

and use the bundle like this:

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg.bookTitle}" filterBy="#{row.book.title}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputText value="#{row.book.title}" />
</p:column>
```

This work perfectly fine.

**Problem:**

Using:

```
book.title=Title
book.url=URL
```

I can't access the values with `#{msg.book.title}` and get the following error message:

```
headerText="#{msg.book.title}": Property [title] not found on type [java.lang.String]
```

I'm using Lombok to generate getters and setters. I fear the problem is that the first key `book` is retrieved as a String and then lombok tries to use the `getTitle()` method on a String object (book) and thus throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
#{msg['book.title']}
```

instead. That should be it.
This is a syntax which, imho, should be used only for keys which have a dot as part of the name.

Btw, Lombok has no part in this.